# How to search for specific string value thats has corresponding text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check for a value that matches in an array of strings.

So something like this works

```
const usernames = ['owlman', 'neo', 'trinity'];
const name = 'neo'

if(usernames.indexOf(name) > -1 ){
  console.log('you found me')
}
else{
  console.log('no luck finding user')
}
```

but what happens if you have a textarea comment, and you want to mention a user with comment data so you do something like this

```
const usernames = ['owlman', 'neo', 'trinity'];
const name = '@neo you look like the one!'

if(usernames.indexOf(name) > -1 ){
  console.log('you found me')
}
else{
  console.log('no luck finding user') // this gets callee
}
```

demo

https://jsbin.com/gepiqopiri/edit?js,console

How can i search for a specific value that is an array when there is corresponding data along with it . Is `indexOf` the approach i want to be using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `name` includes any user from `usernames` as below

```
const usernames = ['owlman', 'neo', 'trinity'];
const name = '@neo you look like the one!';

if(usernames.some(user => name.includes(user))) {
  console.log('you found me'); // this will be called on match
} else {
  console.log('no luck finding user');
}
```

Comment: Used [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#:~:text=The%20some()%20method%20executes,some()%20immediately%20returns%20true%20.) to check atleast one user  incase of multiple users in text area.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` will only find a match for the exact object you pass to it. Your first example works because "neo" does exist as an item in the `usernames` array. Your second example fails, however, because the array does not contain an entry for "@neo you look like the one".

You'll need to parse your `name` string and extract a username, then use `usernames.indexOf` to see if it exists. You can split the `name` string at spaces and then check for a word that begins with '@', or you can use regex.

**Splitting**

```js
var usernames = ['neo', 'other'];
var name = '@neo you look like the one';

// Split the name string at each space
var splitBySpace = name.split(' ');

// Get each item in the split where it begins with @
// The .map uses substring(1) to remove the @ prefix
var atNames = splitBySpace.filter(n => n.indexOf('@') === 0).map(n => n.substring(1));

console.log(atNames[0]);    // neo
console.log(usernames.indexOf(atNames[0]) >= 0);    // true
```

**Regular Expressions**

```js
var usernames = ['neo', 'other'];
var name = '@neo you look like the one @other';

// Get each mentioned name with regex
var atNames = [...name.matchAll(/\@[^\s]+/g)];

// Strip @ prefix from each match
var atNamesToMatch = atNames.map(n => n[0].substring(1));

console.log(atNamesToMatch.length);    // 2 ("neo" and "other")
console.log(usernames.indexOf(atNamesToMatch[0]) >= 0);    // true
console.log(usernames.indexOf(atNamesToMatch[1]) >= 0);    // true
```